# UIWebView: Forcing to landscape (locking) and aspectfit to window

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

All, I have a UIWebView inside a ViewController. The controller is hooked up appropriately and segues properly from the previous tableview. However, I am struggling to accomplish two things: 1. Force the UiWebView (well, the entire scene) to landscape (I am displaying maps from a url) and not allow user rotation, and 2. Have the webview displayed within the constraints of the device. Right now, the UIWebView runs off the screen when displayed as a landscape.

I have tried to reset constraints, update missing constraints, direction lock in storyboard, view>mode>aspectfit in storyboard and forcing it to landscape in the viewcontroller method file (setting to aspectfit instead of aspectfill).

I have read previously questions on here which said it was not possible in previous iOS versions to lock just one scene to portrait/landscape. I have found that this might have changed with iOS7.

I am seeking guidance on how to lock a view and to shrink the webpage displayed in uiwebview to fit the dimensions of the iphone app. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four steps:

1. subclass UINavigationController
2. override the UINavigationController's preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: method

   ```
   (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

   UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
   UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = myDevice.orientation;

   if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   }
   else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
   }
   else {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
   }
   ```

   }
3. set your UIViewController that has the UIWebView as the rootViewController of your subclassed UINavigationController
4. Present your navigationController

If the above doesn't work, try applying the following to your tableViewController (i.e. the viewController that will present your UINavigationController subclass.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

You may also need to add these settings under Target > General.
[image: Device Orientation]

That seems to be all that I did to get a forced landscape orientation working in my app.

Comment: The app crashes, although I know it's something I'm doing wrong. I have subclassed my original nav controller. I implemented the provided code in the new nav controller. I then set the webviewcontroller to the root view controller for the new nav controller. Doing this broke the old segue from my tableviewcontroller, so I reset the segue to go from tableviewcontroller>newnavcontroller. I think my error belongs somewhere in the segue...

Comment: Actually no error now, however, no change in orientation. I have followed your steps and everything is in good order (builds with no errors). Segue from tableviewcontroller goes to newnavcontroller which has the provided code in it. Webviewcontroller is set as the root of this view controller. Upon segueing to the webviewcontroller, the scene still displays in portrait. Could there be something overriding it elsewhere?

Comment: I have some reference code I won't be able to look at until tomorrow. I'll let you know then.

Comment: I'm back at this same issue, shelved it for a few days. Do you happen to have the simple xcodeproj source code for this forced landscape orientation? I've tried to even create a blank app using your methods to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If its the entire application that you'd like to lock into landscape, you can go into your info.plist file and remove the portrait entries from the 'Supported interface orientation' list.